# Xamarin forms: Auto scrolling for CarouselPage children

Tags: xamarin.forms, carousel, autoscroll

I have 4 children (page1,page2,page3, and page4) in a CarouselPage, I need to auto-scroll the children in every 3 seconds. Initially, page1 is showing on the UI, then page2 -> page3 -> page 4 again starting from page1.

I have done like below for this feature using **OnCurrentPageChanged() and await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));**:

```
protected async override void OnCurrentPageChanged()
{
    base.OnCurrentPageChanged();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
    int index = Children.IndexOf(CurrentPage);
    if (index == 0)
    {
        CurrentPage = Children[1];
    }
    else if (index == 1)
    {
        CurrentPage = Children[2];
    }
    else if (index == 2)
    {
        CurrentPage = Children[3];
    }
    else if (index == 3)
    {
        CurrentPage = Children[0];
    }
}
```

The auto-scroll is successful by this approach.

**But if I manually scroll the page in between the auto-scroll, then the time delay is reducing.  Suddenly(less than 3 sec) the next page is showing on the screen. If I manually swipe the page I need to wait on the page for 3 seconds. How can I solve this issue?**

Comment: Do you need Scrolling of pages or Views? If Scrolling of Views is what you need (guessing by the autoscroll feature use are looking for) then I find CarouselPage usage is an overkill.

Comment: @Nikhileshwar  I am trying to scroll of pages, and my pages are the child of CarouselPage

Comment: OK. I will post here if I find any thing useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not put the transfer page to the `OnCurrentPageChanged` method.

You can put it in your Page's constructor.

```
 public partial class MainPage : CarouselPage
{

    bool isStart = true;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3), () =>
        {

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                int index = Children.IndexOf(CurrentPage);
                if (index == 0)
                {
                    CurrentPage = Children[1];
                    isStart = true;
                }
                else if (index == 1)
                {
                    CurrentPage = Children[2];
                    isStart = true;
                }
                else if (index == 2)
                {
                    CurrentPage = Children[3];
                    isStart = true;
                }
                else if (index == 3)
                {
                    CurrentPage = Children[0];
                    isStart = true;
                }
            });
            return isStart; // runs again, or false to stop
        });

    }
  }
```

If you change the page by swipe, the time delay is not reducing.
[image]

However, If you want to wait on the page for 3 seconds after swiping. You have to use custom renderer to achieve it. You should monitor the viewpager's `onTouchEvent`in android(but I cannot found a solution in IOS). This way will have caton, so above way will be better.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CarouselPage), typeof(CustomCarouselPageRenderer))]
namespace CarouselPageDemo.Droid
{
    public class CustomCarouselPageRenderer: CarouselPageRenderer
    {

        public CustomCarouselPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { 

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CarouselPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (this.ChildCount > 0 && this.GetChildAt(0) is ViewPager viewPager)
            {
                viewPager.Touch -= ViewPagerTouched;
                viewPager.Touch += ViewPagerTouched;

            }


        }

        private void ViewPagerTouched(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        {

           MessagingCenter.Send<App, string>(App.Current as App, "OpenPage", "stop");

        }

    }
}
```

`CarouselPage_CurrentPageChanged` method

```
       private async void CarouselPage_CurrentPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              var   tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), tokenSource.Token);
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, string>(App.Current, "OpenPage", (snd, arg) =>
            {

                     tokenSource.Cancel();

                });


            int index = Children.IndexOf(CurrentPage);
            if (index == 0)
            {
                CurrentPage = Children[1];
            }
            else if (index == 1)
            {
                CurrentPage = Children[2];
            }
            else if (index == 2)
            {
                CurrentPage = Children[3];
            }
            else if (index == 3)
            {
                CurrentPage = Children[0];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a Exciting Library **CardsView** please look into it.

it will not only solve your problem but your apps looks cool as well.

here is Source Project , https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/CardView .

check CarouselSampleXamlView in that, **SlideShowDuration** property for carousel which handles all stuff.

Hope it helps.